# How to remove contacts with no relationship to opportunitys

Tags: opportunity

I need to remove contacts which have no relationship to opportunity's. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to remove all Contacts that are not OpportunitiyContactRoles? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query to get all Contacts which are not part of OpportunityContactRole.

```
Select Id from Contact where ID NOT IN (Select ContactId from OpportunityContactRole) limit 1
```

Based on the result size, you can decide to use Workbench or data loader or batch program to delete the contacts.